# I'm using Dakboard kiosk on Raspberry Pi and is there way to code a GPIO button as "F5" keyboard input for refresh?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, kiosk

I made a wall calendar by using old monitor and Raspberry Pi and Dakboard like a kiosk. Sometimes I need to refresh the web page and I use my keyboard <kbd>F5</kbd> button to do that, but I was wondering is there a way to use push button in GPIO to work as a <kbd>F5</kbd> button for refresh my web page?
I used this code to make it autorun:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xest s noblank
@chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --incognito --kiosk http://dakboard.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on quite some options and got a working script now. I'm sure this can be improved, it's tested on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, which handles my keys very slow, and a Raspberry Pi Model 3B+, which handles it fine. I started by creating my own page which handles key-inputs with Javascript.

For your question:

1. Install xdotools.
2. Create an exectuable python3-script (and install python3 ofcourse). My script handles three buttons from ports 17, 27 and 22.

```py
#!/bin/bash

import subprocess

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

print("\n\nscript started\n")

while (True):
    if GPIO.input(17) > 0:
        print("rode knop ingedrukt")
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xdotool", "key", "Right"])
        time.sleep(0.3)

    if GPIO.input(27) > 0:
        print("gele knop ingedrukt")
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xdotool", "key", "0xff0d"])
        time.sleep(0.3)

    if GPIO.input(22) > 0:
        print("groene knop ingedrukt")
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xdotool", "key", "Left"])
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

3. If you want F5 you can use `xdotool key F5`, in python that's `subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xdotool", "key", "F5"])`. I tried removing the print-lines, but then it stopped working. That's probably a timing thing so you should test to add sleep before interacting.
4. Change your autostart script of xserver. Add the python-script `sudo python3 GpioPython.py`, change your display `export DISPLAY=:0` and don't forget the ampersand `&` after the chromium-browser line!

```
xset s off
xset s noblank
xset -dpms

setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

export DISPLAY=:0

chromium-browser --disable-infobars --kiosk 'http:.......' &
sudo python3 GpioPython.py
```

Let me know if the instructions are complete!

Comment: Trying to use your code with RPi4 in kiosk mode (used [this argument list](https://blog.r0b.io/post/minimal-rpi-kiosk/) and a web page with `onkeydown` listening for key press. Getting "Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance". Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you get the error on your terminal or on a connected (physical) display? Can you check if you added the export ```display=:0``` correctly? And added the script of step 4 to the autostart?